# Does Office 2010 integrate with SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, office-integration

We currently have Office 2010 installed and are not looking to upgrade, but want to go to SharePoint for our CMS.  Will the 'Send' feature from MS Word 2010 work with a SharePoint 2013 instance?

Comment: I've had a problem recently with version controlled documents in SP 2010 using Word and Excel 2013. It's detailed here: http://rdsrc.us/PBz7JO I would definitely write a rigorous test plan to validate Office 2013 with any SharePoint 2010 doc management implementation before upgrading a large number of users.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Office 2010 will work fine with SharePoint 2013. The only feature that will not work is the SkyDrive Pro workspace sync from SharePoint 2013.

Comment: For SkyDrive Pro sync with pre Office 2013, you can use the standalone client: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39050.